# Java - Ackley Test Function

Tags: java, mathematical-optimization, evolutionary-algorithm

I am testing a new optimisation algorithm and have a whole test framework in Java. I am comparing this to results from previous papers (one is the well known CLPSO paper). More about the function - http://www.sfu.ca/~ssurjano/ackley.html

The Ackley function is well known and is part of my test suite, THOUGH in my Java implementation of the function I can't seem to get the function minima to be 0, (this should occur at x[i] = 0 for all i). I'm guessing this is some rounding/handling of exp's in Java. Any suggestions for reducing these calculation errors, (it has to be in Java)? My current implementation is:

```
public double f(double[] x) {
double sum1 = 0.0;
double sum2 = 0.0;

for (int i = 0 ; i < x.length ; i ++) {
        sum1 += Math.pow(x[i], 2);
        sum2 += (Math.cos(2*Math.PI*x[i]));
}

return (-20.0 * Math.exp(-0.2 * Math.sqrt(sum1 / ((double )x.length))) - 
                Math.exp(sum2 / ((double )x.length)) + 20.0 + Math.exp(1));
}
```

I currently get the minima value of 8.881784197001252E-16 at my vector X = 0

--something to do with order/brackets…

```
    return -20.0*Math.exp(-0.2*Math.sqrt(sum1 / ((double )x.length))) + 20
                     - Math.exp(sum2 /((double )x.length)) + Math.exp(1.0);
```

Comment: Wondering if on these lines you need:

`sum1 += Math.pow(x[i], 2.0);
sum2 += (Math.cos(2.0*Math.PI*x[i]));`

It might also help to make the last line have `Math.exp(1.0)`

Kind of a similar problem to integer division, but with floor/rounding?

Comment: Hi Jason, unfortunately I wish it was that simple, given that the values are 2 and 1 there should be no typecasting/numerical formatting errors, I tried just to check and still get 8.881784197001252E-16, at my X = 0 vector

Comment: I see. 
To make the question a bit easier to understand, can you add a sample value of the sums that you get in that for loop?

Comment: The sum1 = 0, and sum2 = N (where N is the size of the X vector), so in theory everything should cancel!

Comment: ok solved, it was something to with brackets…i think, I just rearranged it and now it works...

Comment: return -20.0*Math.exp(-0.2*Math.sqrt(sum1 / ((double )x.length))) + 20
                         - Math.exp(sum2 /((double )x.length)) + Math.exp(1.0);

Comment: Interesting, it may help to post what you did as the official answer so others can use it.

Comment: what was your final answer?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was to be with brackets, and the order of calculation (don't ask me how or why!)

```
return -20.0*Math.exp(-0.2*Math.sqrt(sum1 / ((double )x.length))) + 20
                 - Math.exp(sum2 /((double )x.length)) + Math.exp(1.0);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    double fitness=-20.0*Math.exp(-0.2*Math.sqrt(sum1/50.0)) +20.0 - Math.exp(sum2/50.0)+Math.exp(1.0);
```

I don't know why but in this particular order also works. (maybe because of the cancelation of the Math.exp(1.0) )